# Ограничения в RSS для типов материала

Tags: drupal

В мою RSS ленту попадают все типы материалов. Как можно ограничить вывод в RSS для некоторых типов материалов.
Так же хотелось узнать, возможно ли создать 2 отдельные RSS ленты например на новости и товары?
На сколько гибко можно управлять встроенной в друпал системой RSS (я только нашёл ограничения на вывод полей, и общие настройки в конфигурации), есть ли какие-то ещё модули?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите как создавать rss с помощью представлений.

Если здесь /admin/structure/views не включено представление Front page включите его, и будет возможность вносить правки в ленту.